# Does Windows support PEAPv1/EAP-GTC?

Tags: wireless, ieee-802.11

We are running a wireless infrastructure using PEAPv1/EAP-GTC. Our Windows machines can't seem to connect to wireless access points, what is happening?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Naitvely, Windows does not support PEAP-GTC, however there are supplicants available to support PEAP-GTC authentication on Windows.

Answer (score 3):

Windows only supports EAP-TLS and EAP-PEAP/MS-CHAPv2 natively.

If you wanted to add other EAP types, you would have to include a third party supplicant such as:

- Cisco Secure Services Client
- Juniper Odyssey Access Client
- Secure W2 Client

There are many more, some based on specific hardware, but they can support a wide number of different open and proprietary EAP types including EAP-TTLS, EAP-FAST, EAP-LEAP, etc.

Comment: This answer is now dated. Windows now also supports EAP-TTLS natively.

Answer (score 2):

I am aware this question is old - but just wanted to add https://github.com/Amebis/GEANTLink as it might be interesting to someone.

GÉANTLink
Suite of EAP supplicants for Microsoft Windows - IEEE 802.1X clients for enterprise network authentication